# Change delimiter with sed

Tags: csv, server, hdfs, special-characters, delimiter

I have a file with "\001" delimiter inside a server and I want to change the delimiter to "," and the output to be stored in one file.

I tried this:

```
sed 's/\001/^/g' /user/home/test.log > /user/home/output.csv
```

But the output is the same without the new delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tr`:

```
tr '\001' ',' < /user/home/test.log > /user/home/output.csv
```